# how to redirect in WP, BP to a custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to redirect users to a custom page I made when they log in, but I'm not sure I have it right. I don't know exactly which function or variables to use. I want to use the index.php as a way to redirect users. I'm working in wordpress latest, as well as buddypress latest.

So ok, this is what I have:

```
function my_redirect() {
    global $bp;

    if ( $bp->current_component == $bp->root_domain ) {
        bp_core_redirect($bp->root_component == MY_CUSTOM_SLUG  );
    }
}
```

The slug I created is in the root, so it looks like this:
`www.mysite.com/mypage`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using `redirect_to` in your login links. This will require editing of your template.

```
$redirect_url = "www.mysite.com/mypage"
// if $redirect_url exists, it will add it, otherwise print the regular login link
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-login.php<?php
if($redirect_url) {echo "?redirect_to=".urlencode($redirect_url)."\"";}?>  >
log in
</a>
```

This will probably make you want to cut your face off at some point, since you will have to edit the template every time you want to change your redirect page.

Comment: i see...this is what im trying to achieve: when a person logs in, instead of the root ex/ ww.mysite.com, i want them here www.mysite.com/bar. i want that to be my index, that way, i can build everything relative to that component in there, and so on. so when they click on a home link, they always go there

Comment: To change the home link only for logged in users you might want to check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in to see how you can display content only to a user that is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you need this for so here are two ways to do it.

1) You can set any page in wordpress to be the default home page. In the dashboard go to Settings>Reading and under the setting "Front page displays" you can choose "A static page (select below)"

2) You can use the php header location function used:

```
header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;
```

You would place it before your content and it works well with whatever conditions you like.

For more information - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: so i put this at the very top of that page, and it will look to this, and not load the index.php? im not the greatest at php lol...

Comment: I would put it in the template header above the doctype and add the condition `if (is_front_page()) { header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ; }`

Answer (score 1):

You may try the [Login Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/) plugin. You can choose where to redirect the user after login. It is role based.

Comment: hey thanks, i want the user to be redirected there, but will it redirect them there when they click on a home link? i want that component to be my home directory